# Set up Jenkins slave node on Amazon EC2 private subnet (hybrid model)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jenkins

We have a Jenkins master node setup on-premises VMware and our organization has a site-to-site VPN tunnel to the AWS account.
We are trying to set up a slave node in a private subnet on the VPC to which our VPN is set up. 
The guide we are following is https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows

Although we are able to RDP into the AWS EC2 instance from our on-premise machines, we are unable to open the master Jenkins URL on the EC2 instance.

EC2 IP address: 10.45.3.79
RDP from on-premise machine IP: 10.129.32.16
on premise Jenkins IP address: 192.168.17.11

We have checked the following:
Security groups of the EC2 instance allows all traffic from 10.129.0.0/16 and 192.168.0.0/16
Subnet route table redirects all traffic with destination to 192.168.16.0/21 towards the virtual private gateway.

What are we missing that is preventing the ec2 instance in the private subnet to access the Jenkins URL (from the VMware virtual machine on premise)?

Answer (score 0):

I found through the network admins that the firewall on the VMWare was responsible for this issue. Update to the firewall resolved this.